# Javascript - Return value if field is left blank

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm new to coding and I am having trouble returning a value if a field on a form is left blank. The field requires the data input to be between 1 and 10000, if the field is left blank I want -1 as the value. Here is my attempt that is not working....

```
function validatePosition() {
  var position = document.getElementById('Position').value;
  var positionConditions = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (position.match(positionConditions) && (position <= 10000 && position >= 1)) {
    return "";
  } else if (position.value.length == 0) {
    position.value = -1;
  } else {
    return "Error";
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `else if (!position.value || position.value.length == 0)`?

Comment: you assigned `position` to a DOM `.value` property, hence `position` is a `string`. Your line `position.value.length == 0` and the next one are wrong because `position` has not the property `.value`, duh!

Comment: I said I was new to coding, jherax your clearly a prick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position` is the value so `position.value` is not correct:

```js
function validatePosition() {
  var posElement = document.getElementById('Position'),
    posVal = posElement.value,
    positionConditions = /^[0-9]+$/;

  if (posVal.match(positionConditions) && (posVal <= 10000 && posVal >= 1)) {
    return "";
  } else {
    posElement.value = -1;
    return "Error";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="TEXT" name="Position" id="Position">
<input type="submit" onclick="console.log(validatePosition())">
```

Also not sure why you need the else if - surely they are both errors if the length is 0 or it hits the else

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. You were using the value directly, not the element - so setting `position.value` to something new wouldn't work. Setting `position` to something else wouldn't either, as the object reference would be different.
2. You attempted to treat string as an integer, while that may sometimes work, it doesn't for this case

I've commented some of the changes made to make it work.

```js
function validatePosition() {
  // take the whole element, so you could modify contents later.
  // you should only take the value directly if you don't modify it, and
  // only use it for reading purposes
  var position = document.getElementById('Position'); 
  var positionConditions = /^[0-9]+$/;
  console.debug(position.value);
  
  // parse the value into int here, to get a comparable integer and not string. i also
  // modified position to position.value to reflect the earlier comment
  if (position.value.match(positionConditions) && (parseInt(position.value) <= 10000 && parseInt(position.value) >= 1)) {
    console.debug('no error');
    return "";
  } else if (position.value.length == 0) {
    // setting to int works here, but it will be auto converted to string - 
    // might as well keep it consistent
    position.value = "-1";
    console.debug('empty input');
  } else {
    console.debug('out of range');
    return "Error";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Position" onkeyup="validatePosition()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need more information; like if you are coding using HTML5 or not.
So I'm assuming you are talking about a text field I would do as follows.
Also, you said *"The field requires the data input to be between 1 and 10000, if the field is left blank I want -1 as the value.*" I will assume you want the element to be set to -1 and not the function to return -1.  I provided both options.

```
function validatePosition() {
    var position = document.getElementById('Position').value;
    if ((isNaN(position) || position >= 1 || position <= 10000)) {
        return value;
    } else if( position == "" ){
        docucment.getElementById('Position').value = -1;
        // return -1; /** if you want to return the -1 */
    } else {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN